# Calling a function of Express.js in a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a a function in Express.js, using Node.js:

```
app.post("/checkExistsSpecific", function (req, res) {
    // do some code
}
```

I have another function

```
app.post("/checkExistsGeneral", function (req, res) {
    // do some code
    // In this stage, I want to call /checkExistsSpecific API call
}
```

Is there any way to call `app.post("/checkExistsSpecific"..)` from `app.post("/checkExistsGeneral"..)` without using HTTP call?

Comment: do you want to redirect to another post route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to do that, I think you should use named functions as your POST callbacks instead of anonymous as you currently have. This way you can refer to them from wherever you need to.

Something like:

```
function checkExistsSpecific(req, res){
    // do some code
}

app.post("/checkExistsSpecific", checkExistsSpecific);

app.post("/checkExistsGeneral", function (req, res) {
    // do some code
    // In this stage, I want to call /checkExistsSpecific API call

    checkExistsSpecific(req, res);
}
```

Best.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want the function to be called in a normal way:

```
function beingCalled (req, res) {

}


app.post("/checkExistsSpecific", beingCalled );


app.post("/checkExistsGeneral", function (req, res) {
   beingCalled (req,res);

}
```

Or

`response.redirect("/checkExistsSpecific"..)` is what you are looking for(might be).

this will redirect your http call to the  `checkExistsSpecific` route